# Mapping two JavaScript objects and extracting values

Tags: javascript

I have two Objects:

```
"attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "Black"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Eyeball",
      "value": "White"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Eye color",
      "value": "Yellow"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Iris",
      "value": "Small"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Shine",
      "value": "Shapes"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Bottom lid",
      "value": "Low"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Top lid",
      "value": "Middle"
    }
```

and

```
const traits = 
{
  "background": {
    "black": "20%",
    "red": "20%",
    "blue": "30%",
    "yellow": "10%",
    "white": "10%"
  },
  "eyeball": {
    "black": "15%",
    "red": "25%",
    "blue": "35%",
    "yellow": "5%",
    "white": "14%"
  }
}
```

How can I add a third key, value pair in "attributes" with key="rarity" and value = % after matching both trait_type and value in the traits object?

I know how I can do that fairly quickly in Python but I'm new to JavaScript and wonder what's the best and fastest way to solve this.

Comment: please add the wanted result and your try.

Comment: Do you mean to `push` a new item to the array?

Comment: Does your `traits` object have more traits than you've shown here? Such as traits for `"Eye color"`, `"Iris"`, etc.

Comment: Yes the traits object will have all traits that attributes has. The wanted result is to just have also the trait rarity as another key,value pair under attributes

Comment: `trait_type`s shouldn't be having `space`! e.g  `_Top lid_`

Comment: As Nina also asked, please also show your attempt/try, otherwise it makes your question look like no/low effort was put into solving your issue yourself. The approach would be the same as the one you would take in python. You can loop over your objects in `attributes`, and for each object `obj`, add the key `rarity` and set that equal to the associated value from `traits` using bracket notation: `obj.rarity = traits[obj.trait_type.toLowerCase()][obj.value]`, you would need to lowercase the trait type value to match the key from `traits`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You colud do something like:

```js
let attributes = [ { "trait_type": "Background", "value": "Black" }, { "trait_type": "Eyeball", "value": "White" }, { "trait_type": "Eye color", "value": "Yellow" }, { "trait_type": "Iris", "value": "Small" }, { "trait_type": "Shine", "value": "Shapes" }, { "trait_type": "Bottom lid", "value": "Low" }, { "trait_type": "Top lid", "value": "Middle" } ]; 
const traits = { "background": { "black": "20%", "red": "20%", "blue": "30%", "yellow": "10%", "white": "10%" }, "eyeball": { "black": "15%", "red": "25%", "blue": "35%", "yellow": "5%", "white": "14%" } }; 

let result = attributes.map(attr => {
   return {
      "trait_type": attr.trait_type,
      "value": attr.value,
      "rarity": traits[attr.trait_type.toLowerCase()]?.[attr.value.toLowerCase()]
   } 
});

console.log(result);
```

Use `map` to create `result` array with new `rarity` key that looks for percentage value in `traits` object.